# What will the opposite of $this->be() is in a Laravel unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

I'm have a test case with different assertions on it, one of them is for testing the unauthorized access, so I'm trying to log out the user that i previously authenticated with **$this->be($user)**, I need to log out the user, not change the way I'm doing the tests, so I just need something to revert **$this->be()**, but I can't find it.

Comment: Try `$this->be(null)`?

Comment: That's what I thought too but: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::be() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given

Comment: Hmm, that's a pain. Not sure, but you could try `$this->flushSession()`?

Comment: That's the natural solution you would think will work, but it didn't either. Until now i'm refreshing the whole applciaiton to achieve this: $this->refreshApplication(), then i'm running seeding again and all that but ther has to be something opposite to $this->be

Comment: I'm guessing that refreshing the application will do the trick, even though there has to be a way to do it. Must people say $this->flushSession() but it didn't worked for me, maybe because I'm using some other auth middleware for token authentication.

Comment: making a logout(invalidate token) request did the trick.